# Adding null returns integer

Tags: null, addition

In my db table 'maxlimit' field with value null means unlimited, so when i group two rows, 'maxlimit' should be added, and say null+100 should give me null, instead its showing 100.
How should I write it to give me null, which is unlimited?

Comment: First: include the appropriate tag in your question (if you are asking about databases, you should include the corresponding DBMS tag). Second, have you tried anything to fix the problem yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague, but this can help:

```
select (case when maxlimit is null then null else maxlim + 100 end) as maxlim_updated
from yourtable
```

---

Ok, so your comment makes your question a tiny bit more clear... and here is another possible solution:

```
select 
  groupId, 
  case
    when sum(maxlimit is null) > 0 then null
    else sum(maxlimit)
  end as sumOfMaxLimit
from 
  test
group by 
  groupId;
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d0204/5).

---

Some (free) advice:

- Before asking, be sure you try to solve the issue yourself, and post your efforts. Please, read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: select groupid,sum(maxlimit) from mytable group by groupid; if first row is null and second row is 100, i should get null